# How To Set Image From Server As Background Image Of Rect Button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I've been trying to set the background image of a rect button as a .png file I have on my web server. I've declared the button in the view controller .h and added this under .m viewdidload:

```
[mybutton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"http://www.myserver.com/index_files/stacks_image_14.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

but nothing shows in the button. I've been reading on NSSURL to see about calling in images before I try to assign them to objects, but I'm a little stuck at the moment.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: New Code I've tried:

```
 NSURL *myurl2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/bigoaks.png"];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myurl2
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection2= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request2 
                                                                 delegate:self];
    NSString *mystring2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myurl2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; 
    [mybutton setImage : mystring2];
```

Still seem to get "No visible @interface for UIButton declares the selector 'setImage:'

Thanks again for all the assistance!

EDIT 2:

Got it! Thanks for all of the help guys-- here's the final code to help any others:

```
NSURL *myurl2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/bigoaks.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myurl2]];
[mybutton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Using this tutorial: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/download-and-create-an-image-from-a-url.html

Comment: Glad you got it but once again keep in mind that calling URLWith___ on NSURL rather than invoking an asynchronous request has potential to freeze your whole app if the request takes too long (as I said in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/image.png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[mybutton setImage:image];
```

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: I think that's it! Thanks so much for the reply- but I get an error saying "No visible @interface for UIButton declares the selector 'setImage:'

Comment: the last line should be [myButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

imageNamed is for using an image included in your bundle. The other answer is right, although if there is a connection problem, or a delay in general, that code will freeze your UI as it is not asynchronous. Instead, I recommend using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to download the image asynchronously and set the button to use it in the completion delegate function(connectionDidFinishLoading).

Comment: Thanks! EDIT: I added the code I tried (using NSSURL) to original post

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"http://www.myserver.com/index_files/stacks_image_14.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That seems to only give a blank white button-- no image or anything